# Access one of the allowable values for a variable in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I've a typescript definition file such as

```
interface IInterface {
  key:
    | "one"
    | "two"
    | "three";
  selected: boolean;
}
```

Is there anyway I can check whether a variable's value is IInterface.key.one, like it was a standard enum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most type safe approach is to use `typeguards`.

```js
interface IInterface {
  key:
  | "one"
  | "two"
  | "three";
  selected: boolean;
}

const isOne = (key: string): key is 'one' => key === 'one'

const check=(arg:IInterface){
  if(isOne(arg.key)){
    const x = arg // {key: 'one', selected: boolean}
  }
}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) you can find more about typeguards

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean an approach like this?

```
interface IInterface {
  key: "one" | "two" | "three";
  selected: boolean;
}

let testObj = { key: "one", selected: true } as IInterface;

console.log(testObj.key === "one"); // logs true
console.log(testObj.key === "two"); // logs false
```

StackBlitz link to play around with it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-7dsupc?file=index.ts